# Removing duplicates based on systemID, primary key and email

Tags: sql-server, duplicates

I have a table like below

```
1,1@email.com,null
2,1@email.com,systemID2
3,2@email.com,null
4,2@email.com,null
5,3@email.com,systemID3
6,1@email.com,null
```

The table is full of duplicate email addresses. Within these duplicates, some have a 'systemID'
I'm wanting to query all duplicates that do not have a SystemID, (as long as one of the duplicates has a SystemID)

In this example, the query should only give two results:

```
1,1@email.com,null
6,1@email.com,null
```

Comment: What are the names of your columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
;WITH cte
     AS (SELECT Count(1) cnt,a.email
         FROM   tablename a
                JOIN tablename b
                  ON a.email = b.email
         WHERE  a.systemId IS NOT NULL
         GROUP  BY a.email
         HAVING( Count(1) ) > 1)
SELECT b.id,b.email,b.systemId
FROM   cte a
       JOIN tablename b
         ON a.email = b.email
WHERE  b.systemId IS NULL
```

Comment: Yes! Perfect, this is a godsend. Thank you. A thousand times better than what I was trying :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
use tempdb

create table temp(
    id int,
    email varchar(100),
    systemId varchar(100)
)
insert into temp
select 1,'1@email.com',null union  all
select 2,'1@email.com','systemID2' union  all
select 3,'2@email.com',null union  all
select 4,'2@email.com',null union  all
select 5,'3@email.com','systemID3' union  all
select 6,'1@email.com',null

;with cte as(
    select
        *,
        cc = count(*) over(partition by email)
    from temp
)
select 
    t.*
from temp t
inner join cte c
    on c.email = t.email
    and c.cc > 1
    and c.systemId is not null
where
    t.systemId is null
order by email

drop table temp
```